# How to set borders of a custom textbox for PAssword type?

Tags: c#, textbox, passwords

I have 2 text boxes with USername & PAssword. I got a class RoundedCornerTextbox from http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/RoundedCornerTextbox.aspx. It works well with username textbox. But with PAssword textbox it shows actual password instead of "*" - the password char of Textbox.

How can I handle this situation in the RoundedCornerTextbox class ? If I just set the text to "********" (* as many as size of text) in DrawString(), then when I retrieve pswdTxt.Text, the data received will be "*******" only and not actual text.

Comment: Using a completely owner-drawn textbox like that is utterly pointless. It will also be comically easy to extract passwords from it. There's absolutely no reason that you *need* to have slightly rounded corners on your textbox. Use the built-in control that your GUI library offers and everyone's life will be so much better.

Comment: Can you set PasswordChar property?

Comment: @Reniuz: I'm betting there is no `PasswordChar` property on the custom drawn textbox that he's using. That's another reason to use the built-in controls rather than some hackjob controls you found on the Internet: Things work properly.

Comment: @Cody Gray & @Reniuz , It has the PAsswordChar property and I can also set it, but it makes no difference. I tried using owner-draw using WndProc, but that also doesn't work. So am finding a way to handle it in RoundedCornerText class. So how do I work out with it

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3223ht2.aspx The code that custom control is using is quite lousy. Have I mentioned yet that you shouldn't use it?

Comment: If you can help me with WndProoc, kindly look at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/ad00ecac-5d57-4bd0-a6db-859a216e0571/#addcc40e-f238-48b1-9705-618ca4cbefec  . It has all the code.

Comment: @Cody Gray, if not to use custom textbox, then what to do ? How to achieve the rounded corner border for a TExtbox that doesn't have a paint().

Comment: Right, you don't need rounded corners. The standard Windows textbox was never designed to be owner drawn. This problem solves itself if you focus on functionality rather than looking "cool". And I promise that textboxes with rounded corners *don't* look "cool", they look stupid. They look different than all the other textboxes the user has ever seen on their computer.

Comment: @Cody Gray, what can we as a Developer do if it is the customer's strong requirement ! We got to provide a solution (that's what we are for as a Developer) and not just say that what will look good and/or bad. If not custom textbox, what do you recommend for handling to draw the border to a standard textbox using WndProc and handling WM_PAINT. Preferrably provide answer for Why also, for me to understand properly.

Comment: I've never met a customer who "required" round textboxes. That's a stupid requirement. The truth is that customers want applications that are functional. Rounded textboxes are no more functional than the normal-looking ones. As I mentioned before, the standard textbox control is *not* meant to be owner drawn either by handling `WM_PAINT` or otherwise. There's a reason that WinForms *specifically* does not raise the `Paint` event for textboxes. Ignoring this advice and trying to do so anyway is guaranteed to result in nothing but problems. There's nothing wrong with the standard controls.

Comment: @Cody requirement is stupid, but its requirement. Functionality is one thing, designed user interface is other. Also there are many customers who wants nice looking interface beside functionality.

Comment: Your job as a developer is to communicate why that requirement is stupid to the customer. If you can't do that, you're in the wrong profession. If they were the expert on programming, they wouldn't be hiring you in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if you want rounded corner text box, you can use free [Krypton toolkit](http://www.componentfactory.com/product?id=3) textbox component. It supports textbox border rounding. What you need is to set property:

```
int howMuchRoundCorners = 5;
kryptonTextBox.StateCommon.Border.Rounding = howMuchRoundCorners;
```

[image]

Comment: does it support PasswordChar i.e. a textbox for PAssword ? If it does, then only its of any good use to me.

Comment: @Tvd, yes it supports. I added screenshot you can see.

Comment: @Reniuiz, am already downloading it, just asking cna I use the KryptTextBox on a normal Form or got to use it on KryptForm only ??? Your screenshot says you have used normal Form only and not KryptForm, but yet curious to know.

Comment: Yes you can use it on normal form.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Reniuz. I had spent so much time trying to make it as a custom control or over-draw using Wnd-Proc. But your compoent helped me. Thanks